# Different Meanings of "In The Way"

Tags: phrase-meaning, conjunctions

For these two sentences:

1. "People affect the law ***in the way*** it affects people."
2. "People discuss the law ***in the way*** it affects people."

, could "*in the way*" have different meanings in the two sentences?

EDIT ADDITION:

But "*in the way*" appears to be often suggested as a definition for "*as*" when "*as*" is used in my original sentences like this:

> 1a. "People affect the law ***as*** it affects people."
>   2a. "People discuss the law ***as*** it affects people."

What do the "*as*" in 1a and 2a mean?  Are the *as*'s in 1a and 2a different?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can... but I think the second one is an error.

> *People affect the law **in the way** it affects people.*

This sense of **in the way** means "the very same way that" or "identically to".  So this sentence is saying that people and the law mutually affect one another in just the same way.

> *People discuss the law **in the way** it affects people.*

I think this is a common English usage mistake, arising from mishearing **and the way** and mistaking it for the previous idiom.  So what this sentence is saying is that people discuss two topics, first being the law itself, and second being the way the law affect people.

Comment: My reply would've been too long for the comment section, so I added my reply and further question to my original question. I would be greatly obliged if you could provide another helpful answer to that new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, the meanings of in the way in these two sentences are the same. In the way means "...in the same way that...".The second sentence is a bit confusing, you usually use the same verb if you use in the way. The first sentence mean(you might want the opposite of this meaning) that:

> 1. People see how the law affects people
> 2. People copy the way the law affects people and apply that way to the law itself

If you want to say the people affects the law first, just reverse it:

> The law affects people in the way people affect the law.

To the edit:

1a can be understood in two ways.

> 1. People affect the law while it affects people.
> 2. People affect the law in the same way that it affects people.

2a can be understood like:

> People discuss the law while it affects people.

Comment: My reply comment is too long, so I added it to my original question. Thanks!

Comment: OK, Your welcome!

Comment: No, I meant my reply would've been too long for the comment section, so I added my reply and further question to my original question.  I would be greatly obliged if you could provide another helpful answer to that new question.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh! OK, sorry. I will.

Comment: There, I just edited it.